# If $f(x+a)-f(x)$ is differentiable for each $a$, then $f$ is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

$ f \in C(\mathbf{R})$, if for each real $a$, $f(x+a)-f(x)$ is differentiable, then $f$ is differentiable.

It seems hard to convert difference to the original function

Comment: Is the hypothesis that there exists an $a$ so that $f(x+a)-f(x)$ is differentiable or is it that for each $a$ the function $x\mapsto f(x+a)-f(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: There's an "if" missing at some point before the "then", and it matters for the meaning where you put it. Please edit the question.

Comment: @kimchilover It has to be for all $a$, otherwise any periodic nondifferentiable function is a counterexample...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This and many other results of this kind are proved in the paper

> [Bruijn, de, N. G. (1951). Functions whose differences belong to a given class. *Nieuw Archief voor Wiskunde, serie 2, 23,* 194-218.](https://research.tue.nl/en/publications/functions-whose-differences-belong-to-a-given-class)

The assumption that $f(x)$ is continuous can be weakened, e.g., it's enough to assume that $f(x)$ is bounded on a set of positive measure. Some condition on $f(x)$ is needed since, if $f(x)$ is a discontinuous additive function, then $x\mapsto f(x+a)-f(x)$ is the constant function $x\mapsto f(a)$.